# AJAX not sending valid data based on DOM elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, dom

I have a generic issue that happens intermittently when sending data of a DOM element to the server through AJAX and I cannot find a way to reproduce them.

There are a bunch of pages that send data from the DOM (like `$("#id").val()` or `$("#form").serialize()`) through AJAX and in some cases users throws exceptions like:

> "Cannot convert id 'undefined' to Long" - when trying to manipulate an id that should be a number
>
> "page is not present" - when Spring MVC Controllers try to use the data sent from a form ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956844/spring-mvc-requestparamexception-parameter-is-not-present))

One way I was able to reproduce some of these cases was by bursting a lot of page refreshes on pages that have an AJAX call fired on page load, but not on pages that have AJAX calls on user interactions (like a button click).

I am really confused with this issue, because if I switch from `$(document).ready()` calls to `$(window).load()` I won't get exceptions on the pages that have AJAX calls on page load, but this is not the right way to solve it for this case, since I don't want/have to wait scripts and images to load and it doesn't solve the problem for pages that have AJAX bound to user events.

I assume that the server is always sending the correct DOM to users (since I was never able to reproduce most cases), so what can be happening to get those exceptions?

Comment: it's always wise to check the data in the fron-end before seding it to the back-end, why not do that then?

Comment: I totally agree with you, but if I do that I will just avoid getting exceptions and won't find out why it is happening. I wan't to avoid the error, not to handle it

Comment: as you said in your question (if I understood correctly), it happens because some of the data aren't loaded while the ajax calls are being fired, so a way would be to write those ajax calls in a function, check the data in the function, if they were not what you wanted then loop the function and have it to start again with a little interval.

Comment: @AminJafari The issue that I am trying to solve isn't the exception that is thrown sometimes, what I am trying to solve is why is the data/DOM not being loaded correctly sometimes! (Since some exception have to be handled on the server side)